# How to create a local Python package for modules that I use for several different projects

Tags: python, version-control, package

I have several sets of utility functions that I have written to analyze scientific data. For example, for making plots I might have a file called `plotting_tools.py`

For several different projects in several different home directories and virtual environments, I might want to use functions from `plotting_tools.py` One way to do this is to have a copy of `plotting_tools.py` in every project directory, and then just run

```
from plotting_tools.py import *
```

at the top of my workflow (for example, in a Jupyter notebook).

However, this approach has limitations because when I discover a bug in `plotting_tools.py` I have to manually update every local copy. Another option is to have a single directory on my computer from which I import the module using importlib

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

foo = SourceFileLoader("plotting_tools","/Users/me/plotting_tools.py").load_module()
from plotting_tools.py import *
```

This is a little frail because it has a hard coded directory, and tools like `autoreload()` break.

I was curious if there is a way to deal with this problem more elegantly, where I have some sort of local directory with all of my utility function files that can be treated as a package (as in, when I make a new project and virtual environment I can just install the current version of `plotting_tools` to that environment, and then manually update it if the master version changes). Is the best way to do this just to use a GitHub repository for all of my functions, or is there a way to do this purely locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create a local library by using [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/library/distutils.html).

you can create a setup.py and define your library structure there.
then you can do

> python setup.py install

and it would install library to your system or virtualenv with the package structure you defined and then you can import from that package in your other projects.
it's similar of doing

> pip install package

but this would be locally.

here's the example of setup.py you can define.

assuming you have defined your utility project as `utils`

```
from distutils.core import setup
from utils.version import __version__

setup(
    name='utils',
    version=__version__,
    description='utility library',
    author='Asav Patel',
    author_email='',
    requires=['tornado',
              'sqlalchemy', ],
    py_modules=['config'],
    install_requires=[ 'psutil'
                    ],
    packages=['utils',
              'polotting_lib', 'polotting_lib.graph', 'polotting_lib.maps',
              'other_packages'],
    package_data={
        'polotting_lib': ['*'],
    },
)
```

then just do

> python setup.py install

After this in your other scripts you can do.

```
from polotting_lib import *

def foo(*args):
    some_method_from_plotting_lib(args)
```

hope this helps.

Comment: https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html Just FYI !